# Is there a linear algebra library for OCaml that takes advantage of vectorization?

Tags: ocaml, linear-algebra

Just wondering if there are any linear algebra libraries for OCaml that take advantage of vectorization on the CPU.

Comment: which type of chip are you using? Intel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LACAML](https://mmottl.github.io/lacaml/) is a linear algebra library which interfaces with the BLAS and LAPACK Fortran libraries. If you have an Intel chip, it will hit the MKL libraries which are highly optimised.